# Android performance Optimization with Android Profiler

Tags: android, performance, performance-testing, android-traceview, android-profiler

I know about the Android Profiler and Traceview, but I would like to know, if I can check exactly which line of code is causing the high performance usage of my app.

Thank you very much!